# Need help in understanding tagged templates

Tags: javascript

I have two code snippets which are using [tagged template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates) feature of template literals

Code one

```js
function myTaggedLiteral(strings, value, value2) {
  console.log(strings, value, value2);
}

let someText = 'Neat';
myTaggedLiteral `test ${someText} ${2 + 3} test2`;
```

In this case it will log

```
[
  "test ",
  " ",
  " test2"
] Neat 5
```

This another example is from mdn

```js
var person = 'Mike';
var age = 28;

function myTag(strings, personExp, ageExp) {
  console.log(strings, personExp, ageExp)
  // some other code
}
var output = myTag `That ${ person } is a ${ age }`;
```

This will log

```
[
  "That ",
  " is a ",
  ""
] Mike 28
```

So in first log there is an empty string `""` after `test` , my understanding was this of the template expression `${someText} ${2 + 3}` but in the second log there is no `""` after `That` , although both of function is called in almost same structure of parameters.

**Will really appreciate if someone helps me to understand why there is an empty string after test in the first log.**

Secondly if I tweak the first program

```js
function myTaggedLiteral(strings, value, value2) {
  console.log(strings);
}

let someText = 'Neat';
myTaggedLiteral `test test6 test3 ${someText} ${2 + 3}`;
```

and this will log

```
[
  "test test6 test3 ",
  " ",
  ""
]
```

As per mdn

> The first argument of a tag function contains an array of string
>   values.

If that is so then why it is outputting the first value as `"test test6 test3 "` instead of `"test","test6","test3"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the `strings` parameter like the result of a [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) where the separator is any [placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Description), aka

> ... indicated by the dollar sign and curly braces (`${expression}`).

Here's an example

```js
let templateString = 'test test6 test3 ${someText} ${2 + 3}'
let strings = templateString.split(/\$\{.*?}/) // regex for a placeholder

console.log(strings)
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Description)...

> If `separator` appears at the beginning or end of the string, or both, the array begins, ends, or both begins and ends, respectively, with an empty string

That is why, if any placeholders appear at the boundaries of your string, you will get empty strings in the resulting array.

In this you can always be sure that `strings` will have one more entry than there are placeholder expressions. Creating the resulting string will always involve (ignoring any extra transformations you might want to do)...

```js
strings[0] + arg[0] +
strings[1] + arg[1] +
...                     
strings[n] + arg[n] + strings[n+1]
```

where *`n`* is the number of placeholders.

Comment: thanks , for helping me to understand that position of the separator/delimiter is the main reason